# Copy all repeated tags at same place

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using xslt 1.0 and I have below input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root>
<tag1>1<tags>
<tag1_1>not repeating<tag1_1>
<tag2>2<tag2>
<tag3>3<tag3>
<tag4>4<tag4>
<tag5>5<tag5>
<tag6>6<tag6>
<tag2>2<tag2>
<tag3>3<tag3>
<tag1>1<tag1>
<tag4>4<tag4>
<tag1>1<tag1>
<tag3>3<tag3>
<tag2>2<tag2>
<tag4>4<tag4>
<tag4>4<tag4>
<tag2>2<tag2>
<tag1>1<tag1>
<tag3>3<tag3>
</root>
```

I need to create a xslt to create an XML which will have all identical at one place.

Now I want to have all same tag that are repeating should display at a single place one by one
And my output should be like below
Output xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root>
<tag1>1<tag1>
<tag1_1>not repeating<tag1_1>
<tag2>2<tag2>
<tag3>3<tag3>
<tag4>4<tag4>
<tag5>5<tag5>
<tag6>6<tag6>
<tag1>1<tag1>
<tag2>2<tag2>
<tag3>3<tag3>
<tag4>4<tag4>
<tag1>1<tag1>
<tag2>2<tag2>
<tag3>3<tag3>
<tag4>4<tag4>
<tag1>1<tag1>
<tag2>2<tag2>
<tag3>3<tag3>
<tag4>4<tag4>
</root>
```

Comment: FYI: Your XML is not well formed.  All of your begin and end tags don't match and the end tags do not have a forward slash.

Comment: Let's say you have the following tags in your xml in this order:  1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1.  Would the result be group one = 1, 2 and group two = 1, 2, 3, 4?  Or, group one = 1, 2, 3, 4 and group two = 1, 2?  And how did you make that decision?

Comment: The logic you want to implement is not clear.  --- And also: *"I am using xslt 1.0*" Then why did you add the `xslt-2.0` tag??

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- key on element to be sorted.  -->
<xsl:key name="myKey" match="*[contains(local-name(), 'tag') and . != 'not repeating']" use="generate-id(.)"/>

<!-- Get metadata containing elements to be sorted.  -->
<xsl:variable name="originalTags">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[contains(local-name(), 'tag') and . != 'not repeating']" mode="original"/>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- Create a node set.  Be sure to use your own prefix for node-set. -->
<xsl:variable name="originalTagList" select="msxml:node-set($originalTags)"/>

<!-- Put the elements into groups. -->
<xsl:variable name="groups">
  <xsl:call-template name="getGroups">
    <xsl:with-param name="group" select="1"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="index" select="1"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="values" select="''"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="length" select="count($originalTagList/tag)"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="groupList" select="msxml:node-set($groups)"/>
  
<!-- Sort by group and value. -->
<xsl:variable name="sortedTags">
  <xsl:for-each select="$groupList/tag">
    <xsl:sort select="group" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:sort select="value" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:element name="tag">
      <xsl:copy-of select="id"/>
      <xsl:element name="position">
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="sortedTagList" select="msxml:node-set($sortedTags)"/>

<!-- Output the sorted elements. -->
<xsl:template match="*[contains(local-name(), 'tag') and . != 'not repeating']">
  <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id(.)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="originalPosition" select="$originalTagList/tag[id = $id]/position"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="key('myKey', $sortedTagList/tag[position = $originalPosition]/id)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="getGroups">
  <xsl:param name="group"/>
  <xsl:param name="index"/>
  <xsl:param name="values"/>
  <xsl:param name="length"/>

  <xsl:variable name="value" select="$originalTagList/tag[number($index)]/value"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$index &gt; $length">
      <xsl:variable name="exit" select="0"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <!-- If this is a duplicate value, the start a new group with this value. -->
    <xsl:when test="contains($values, concat('|', $value, '|'))">
      <xsl:call-template name="getGroups">
        <xsl:with-param name="group" select="$group + 1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="values" select="''"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$length"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:element name="tag">
        <xsl:element name="id">
          <xsl:value-of select="$originalTagList/tag[number($index)]/id"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="position">
          <xsl:value-of select="$originalTagList/tag[number($index)]/position"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="group">
          <xsl:value-of select="$group"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="value">
          <xsl:value-of select="$originalTagList/tag[number($index)]/value"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    
      <xsl:call-template name="getGroups">
        <xsl:with-param name="group" select="$group"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="values" select="concat($values, '|', $originalTagList/tag[number($index)]/value, '|')"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$length"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<!-- **************** original mode ***************-->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="original">
  <xsl:element name="tag">
    <xsl:element name="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="position">
      <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="value">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<!-- ********************************************* -->
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of what is it that your code is designed to accomplish. As it stands, it's hard to tell whether that's the best way to accomplish it (though it seems unlikely).

Comment: The grouping is the only tricky part.  The idea is that each group has unique values.  As soon as a duplicate value is found in the getGroups template a new group is started.  The sorting is done using push programming because the "not repeating" tags are not sorted and need to be left alone.  So a for-each loop can't be used.  The sort swaps the original tag with the sorted tag.  That's it.  After changing the XML to be well formed this code with transform it as requested.  I'm open to see better ways of doing this, so I can learn.  Thanks.